# Show that $\mu\left( \bigcap_{i=1}^n A_i\right )\gt 0$

Tags: real-analysis, probability, sequences-and-series, measure-theory, probability-theory

let $(\Omega, F, P)$ be a probability space and suppose the sets $A_1, A_2,...,A_n \in F$satisfy the inequality $$\sum_{i=1}^n\mu(A_i) \gt n-1$$

Show that $$\mu\left( \bigcap_{i=1}^n A_i \right) \gt 0$$

I think how to show this question. but I cannot find any solution way, thus, I cannot write any idea. Please help me showing this question. Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We have

$$1 - \mu\left(\bigcap_{i = 1}^n A_i\right) = \mu\left(\bigcup_{i = 1}^n A_i^c\right) \le \sum_{i = 1}^n \mu(A_i^c) = \sum_{i = 1}^n [1 - \mu(A_i)] = n - \sum_{i = 1}^n \mu(A_i) < 1,$$

and so

$$\mu\left(\bigcap_{i = 1}^n A_i\right) > 0.$$