# Probability of intersection of some $k$ events is non zero

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

> Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ be a probability space and suppose that for
> $A_1, \dots, A_n \in \mathcal{F}$ it holds $P(A_1)+\dots+P(A_n) 
> > k-1$, for some $k\in \mathbb{N}$. Prove that there exist indices
> $1\leq i_1 < \dots < i_k \leq n$ such that $P(A_{i_1}\cap \dots \cap
> > A_{i_k}) > 0$

The case $k=n$ is a standard exercise and can be found on MSE ([here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1209468/show-that-mu-left-bigcap-i-1n-a-i-right-gt-0?noredirect=1) for example). For the general case, I tried arguing as follows:
Let $X=\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbf{1}_{A_i}$, so $\mathbb{E}[X]>k-1$. Then, the union of all possible intersections of exactly $k$ of the events $A_i$ is exactly the event $\{X=k\}$. So
$$\sum_{1\leq i_1 < \dots < i_k \leq n}P(A_{i_1}\cap \dots \cap A_{i_k}) \geq P(X=k)=\mathbb{E}[\mathbf{1}_{\{X=k\}}]$$
If we can show that the RHS is positive then we are done. But I'm stuck since everything I try seems to only work for the case $k=n$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were almost there!

If $\omega\in A_{i_1}\cap\cdots\cap A_{i_k}$, then $$X(\omega)=k+\sum_{i\ne i_1,\ldots, i_k}\textbf{1}_{A_i}(\omega)$$
Thus $P(A_{i_1}\cap\cdots\cap A_{i_k})=P(X\ge k)$.

Now of $P(X\ge k)=0$, then we must have $\mathbb{E}(X)\le k-1$, contradicting the assumption.

Answer (score 2):

Note that: $$P(X\geq k)>0\implies\text{indices }i_1,\dots,i_k\text{ exist with }P(A_{i_1}\cap\cdots\cap A_{i_k})>0$$

Now suppose that indices like that do **not** exist.

Then $P(X\leq k-1)=1-P(X\geq k)=1-0=1$ and consequently: $$P\left(A_{1}\right)+\cdots+P\left(A_{n}\right)=\mathbb{E}X\leq k-1$$